# I can't place textview under my Image in Android Studio?

Tags: android

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

I use this code for TextView

Comment: You should use layout

Comment: What layout are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to add DrawableTop:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/yourimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

I also saw you have 0dp width and wrap_content, I am assuming you are using layout weights, and not constraint layout. So please do experiment with that.

You can also add `android:drawablePadding="dp"` to add padding in image to text.